# Express-validator validation error variable throwing 'undefined' error on page load

Tags: javascript, express, ejs, express-validator

I am working on a contact form and using express-validator for validation. I am trying to handle errors and this is my code in my app.js file so far (the relevant snippet):

```
// CREATE (POST) ROUTE - add new prospect to the DB
app.post('/contact', [
check('firstName', 'Please enter at least one letter').not().isEmpty().trim().escape(),
check('lastName', 'Please enter at least one letter').not().isEmpty().trim().escape(),
check('emailAddress', 'Please enter a valid email address').isEmail().normalizeEmail(),
check('message', 'Please enter at least one letter').not().isEmpty().trim().escape()
], (req, res) => {

// GET AND SANITIZE DATA
var firstname = req.sanitize(req.body.firstName);
var lastname = req.sanitize(req.body.lastName);
var emailaddress = req.sanitize(req.body.emailAddress);
var message = req.sanitize(req.body.message);
var newProspect = { firstName: firstname, lastName: lastname, emailAddress: emailaddress, phoneNumber: phonenumber, message: message };

// HANDLE FORM VALIDATION ERRORS
const errors = validationResult(req);
if(!errors.isEmpty()) {
    console.log(errors.array());
    return res.status(422).render('contact-form', {
        errorMessage: errors.array()[0].msg
    });
}
```

To output the errors to the browser, I have the following in my contact-form.ejs file just above the actual form div:

```
<% if(errorMessage) { %>
    <div class="user-message user-message--error"><%= errorMessage %></div>
<% } %>
```

When I load the route for the contact-form, I get the following error:

```
ReferenceError: /home/ubuntu/workspace/views/contact-form.ejs:13
    11|<p class="lead">Fill out the form below and we will respond as soon as possible.

    12|</p>

 >> 13|<% if(errorMessage) { %>

    14|<div class="user-message user-message--error"><%= errorMessage %></div>

    15|<% } %>

    16|<div class="form">


errorMessage is not defined
```

I know I am missing something here, but in my admitted inexperience, it's just not that obvious to me what exactly it is.

Maybe the question is better asked, what is the catch on using the 'errorMessage' variable from my app.js in my contact-form.ejs template effectively and successfully so that I don't get the 'undefined' error?

Comment: I see you're already outputting the errors.array(). What does that show you? Does it look like there is in fact (at least) one element, and that element is an object with a `msg` key?

Comment: Actually, without the 'if' in the contact-form.ejs template, I was successfully getting errors via the console.log line in my app.js file. But with the addition of the 'if' in the contact-form.ejs, simply loading the contact form to the browser throws the error and stops the server.

Comment: [ { location: 'body',
    param: 'firstName',
    value: '',
    msg: 'Please enter at least one letter' },
  { location: 'body',
    param: 'lastName',
    value: '',
    msg: 'Please enter at least one letter' },
  { location: 'body',
    param: 'emailAddress',
    value: '',
    msg: 'Please enter a valid email address' },
  { location: 'body',
    param: 'message',
    value: '',
    msg: 'Please enter at least one letter' } ]

Answer (score 0):

I think you may have a scope issue. Where is the `errorMessage` variable declared? Either your quoted code does not show where that is or it is implicitly declared inside the `!errors.isEmpty` control structure, in which case it is not available to the global scope and the `errorMessage` variable you invoke later on is indeed not defined. 

I cannot test with the code you have included, but having had similar issues in the past, I tended to find that scope was the issue. Hopefully it is here too and you can be on your way to a solution. If not, post again and we will try to have another look :).
HTH -- Philippe